# converting data formating (german) to universal - python pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with german formatted data, that ie `1,29` in universal format means `1.29` while `1.56` in universal  format means `156` pieces, currently my python script is reading `1,29` as a string and `1.56` as `1.56` whereas in my ideal solution it should be `1.29` float  and `156` as integer.

Also, the correct value for this `24.386999999999997`  in CSV file is `24.387` which in reality means `24387` (integer) but pandas
is reading otherwise.

The data is as below

```
Row    Date    c_s  eV      eC_r    D_O_p   D_Q_p   D_V_E_p 
1   2018-03-01  FR  34.598  1,29    445.0   1.56    24.386999999999997  
2   2018-03-01  DE  159.779 3,01    4.804   24.976  407.38300000000004  
3   2018-03-01  AT  19.878  4,96    985.0   7.703   93.19   
4   2018-03-01  PL  42.387  3,37    1.428   7.478   68.816
```

any suggestions would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: 1.56 is not a valid german format. 1.560 would be.

Comment: more important then what is displayed would be **what types are your columns**  - it seems / could be that `eC_r` is a string column  - same for the othersones

Comment: read all of them as ``str`` and do ``.replace('.', '')`` and ``.replace(',', '.')`` and convert them to ``float`` again

Comment: @karina ill avice - there is a mix of formats - f.e. 407.38300000000004 seems ok

Comment: @PatrickArtner ups yeah, you are right, I missed that. A workaround that I often do is just to do it column wise, since every time the csv data is reloaded, the comma can sometime change itself to dot, regardless of the language setting of the computer itself. Happens a lot. Surely not ideal, but working just fine

Comment: 1.56 means 156 pieces. So it can't be 1.560

Comment: everything with . is actually an integer - basically whole number...and everything with, is actually a float where we will need 3 points after decimal

Comment: @sdave if automation is not a big issue, you could do as I said above, ``replace`` according to your need for each data column.

Comment: @Karina that's the issue, everyday I receive a new file with almost 1000000 rows. I can't be sure if .replace will work fine always

Comment: the row is not the problem, the column is, I mean, in a column, all data are stored with the same format, right? but I do admit it is not ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas `read_csv` allows you to set the thousands and decimal separators:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', delim_whitespace=True, thousands='.', decimal=',', parse_dates=['Date'])
```

Would output:

|  | Row | Date | c_s | eV | eC_r | D_O_p | D_Q_p | D_V_E_p |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2018-03-01 00:00:00 | FR | 34598 | 1.29 | 4450 | 156 | 24386999999999997 |
| 1 | 2 | 2018-03-01 00:00:00 | DE | 159779 | 3.01 | 4804 | 24976 | 40738300000000004 |
| 2 | 3 | 2018-03-01 00:00:00 | AT | 19878 | 4.96 | 9850 | 7703 | 9319 |
| 3 | 4 | 2018-03-01 00:00:00 | PL | 42387 | 3.37 | 1428 | 7478 | 68816 |

Now if I understand correctly, if there are more than 3 digits after the period, everything thereafter should actually be after the comma. In such cases you can write a converter and apply that to the respective column:

```
def process_number(x):
    if len(x.split('.')[-1]) > 3 :
        idx = len(x) - x[::-1].index('.') - 1 #get index number of last occurence of .
        x = x[:idx+4] + ',' + x[idx+4:] #insert comma
        x= x.replace('.','').replace(',','.') #remove periods and replace comma
        return int(round(float(x))) #convert to int
    else:
        return int(x.replace('.',''))
    
converters = {'D_V_E_p': lambda x: process_number(x)}
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', delim_whitespace=True, thousands='.', decimal=',', parse_dates=['Date'], converters=converters)
```

Output:

|  | Row | Date | c_s | eV | eC_r | D_O_p | D_Q_p | D_V_E_p |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2018-03-01 00:00:00 | FR | 34598 | 1.29 | 4450 | 156 | 24387 |
| 1 | 2 | 2018-03-01 00:00:00 | DE | 159779 | 3.01 | 4804 | 24976 | 407383 |
| 2 | 3 | 2018-03-01 00:00:00 | AT | 19878 | 4.96 | 9850 | 7703 | 9319 |
| 3 | 4 | 2018-03-01 00:00:00 | PL | 42387 | 3.37 | 1428 | 7478 | 68816 |

Comment: what if I only need ```2018-03-01``` instead of ```2018-03-01 00:00:00```? how can we do that?

Comment: I am getting this error while loading it to bigquery 

```Could not parse '2018-01-03 00:00:00.000000' as DATE for field Date (position 0) starting at location 0  with message 'Unable to parse' ```

Comment: @sdave `2018-03-01 00:00:00` is just the representation of a datetime object. You can remove `parse_dates=['Date']` from the code to avoid parsing the date to keep the string representation.

Comment: in that case, the ```thousands ='.'``` operator works on the 'date' column as well and convert it to an integer. 

```df = pd.read_csv('/content/test.csv', encoding='utf-16le', sep = ';', thousands='.', decimal=',', parse_dates=['Date'], date_parser = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d.%m.%Y'))```
I will see if it works

Comment: @sdave yes or you could add something like this to the converters dictionary: `'Date': lambda x: x[:10]` or `'Date': lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x[:10])`.

Comment: actually, I don't want DateTime but just date, eventually I need to load it to bigquery and even if it's in object/string format, I can specify it as a date in bigquery schema. Anyways, your solution helped. Thanks! ;)